# How can I find my app files under iPhone Simulator folder?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

How can I easily access to the folder of an app I am working on.

[image]

There are too many application folders under iPhone Simulator directory, how can I access to any specific folder?

Comment: There are lots of applications in your simulator. First reset your simulator and then run your project then you will be able to find your app easily.

Comment: First delete all application from iPhone simulator and then run you application ... the Application name is under the unique folder which display under "Applications" folder.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do this programatically:

```
NSLog(@"%@",[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]);
```

Comment: Pretty shocking that I have to edit my source code, recompile, run, check the log, copy the output, open a finder window, Cmd+Shift+G, paste... there really ought to be a quick option to open the folder from Xcode (especially when they keep moving the folder in each Xcode update!!)

Answer (score 9):

I know of 2 great mac apps that solve your problem:

1. SimPholders
   http://simpholders.com/
2. Simulator Folders
   http://nimbleworks.co.uk/blog/simulator-folders/

Answer (score 2):

You can use [OpenSim](https://github.com/luosheng/OpenSim) as an alternate tool of above mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can see you app name  and then you can find it easily..So try to implement this.

```
 NSString *path = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"Path %@",path);
```