# Look inside Apps folder

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, ios-simulator

is there a way to navigate inside the folder structure in iPad or iPhone, check what is inside of any app folder? I tried already xcode but can not identify the folders. Thanks...

Comment: No, each app is sandboxed and can't access anything outside of it's designated area.

Comment: similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19130439/how-can-i-find-my-app-files-under-iphone-simulator-folder

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it on a real device, but you can have a look on the simulator. Up until iOS 7 each iOS version maintains it's own set of apps under

Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/

followed by a cryptic number representing your app. Replace 7.1 with another iOS version. To display the Library folder in Finder, click Go from the Finder menu while holding down Option.

Since iOS 8 those locations have moved and are harder to find. See here: http://pinkstone.co.uk/where-is-the-documents-directory-for-the-ios-8-simulator/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use programs like "iExplorer" which let you navigate your device even without jailbroken devices. I often use it to check that my app is correctly creating files according to my coded file structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can see only contents of Documents Directory on Simulator or device. If you want to see documents directory in device then you have to set UIFileSharingEnabled key to YES in your application's Info.plist file. Then you can see it via iTunes app in Mac os x.

There is not way to see bundle contents in application. Just you can see bundle contents in xcode.

Regards.